# get request "No overload matches this call" Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a GET method in my backend where I send a request body as input and get a list of results as return.

Now in my frontend I have:

```
  search(cat: Cat): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Cat[]>(this.messageBaseUri+'/search', cat);
  }
```

The error I am getting is in VsCode:

```
    (parameter) cat: Cat
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Cat' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Property 'observe' is missing in type 'Cat' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Overload 2 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Cat' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Property 'observe' is missing in type 'Cat' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Overload 3 of 15, '(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Cat' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.ts(2769)
http.d.ts(939, 9): 'observe' is declared here.
http.d.ts(1049, 9): 'observe' is declared here.
Peek Problem
No quick fixes available
```

I read here https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/635 that GET request can't have body as input parameter, but how am I able to send a request body through for Example Postman and get a return without an error?

Comment: There is no body in GET  - `, cat`, you can pass HttpOptions with HttpParams in it, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no body for get . You can pass the url and options to get request.

you can see the various overloads of get in the following link
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get